# Firefox shows blue box around image link

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, border

I have an anchor tag around all of these images on my site. When you click it, it scrolls to the id "template".

```
<a class="hi" href="#template"><img src="images/01.png" /></a>
```

I have tried every trick in the book.

```
a img{border:none; outline: none;}
```

`border=0` in the image tag itself.

No matter what I do there's always a blue border around the image once you click it.  Click any of the circle images (towards the bottom) for reference.  Remember, to view in Firefox.

http://stevendennett.com/newsite/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to remove the border by setting the anchor color to transparent:

```
a.hi {
  color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The dotted border around the image is the Outline of the `<a>` tag. So that, when you remove the border and outline in `img` it will not be the solution.

**The solution is**

We don't need to put to much code. Try here:

```
a { /* Remove all the outline border all in our document. */
   outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a.hi {
    outline: none;
    color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a.hi {
    outline: medium none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The image works fine in Chrome and Opera (15+).

So the issue that is happening is the default effect of the browser, here is what happens in FF.

[image]

And the IE (10):

[image]

But its fine in Chrome, which means that there is no such effect in CSS.

So you must try and add this :

```
a > img {
   border: 0;
}
```

It will remove the borders from all the images which are direct under the `a` hyperlinks.

**Look at your code:**

In your css file, on line 35 (if I am not wrong) you are having `outline: medium none` and `border: medium none;`

I removed that, and there was no border! Try it :)